# Open/close ngx-material-keyboard using a toggle option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I just started developing applications using 
**Angular 5**. I need to integrate [ngx-material-keyboard](https://github.com/ngx-material-keyboard/core) into my application.

I'm able to integrate it to an input field by adding `[matKeyboard]="'en-US'"` to it. Now, onfocus in input field, virtual keyboard is shown, onblur its getting closed.

Now how can I control the opening and closing of keyboard integrated to input field using a toggle option or button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Control of the virtual keyboard is provided through [MatKeyboardService](https://ngx-material-keyboard.github.io/core/injectables/MatKeyboardService.html).